# Skin modifier applied to disjoint mesh

Tags: modifiers, geometry

I have a mesh made only of edges. If the mesh have only one connected component, then I can apply a skin modifier and get something with surface that I can render.

This is the input mesh
[image]

Ahd this is what I get after applying the skin modifier

[image]

As you can see, only one of the components of the mesh has the skin modifier applied. I can't separate the mesh into different separate components. I have thousands of meshes like this and won't be practical.

I would like to know if there is some way to get something similar to what I am expecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select a vertex of the edge where the skin modifier fails and click on 'mark root', you will have to do this for every piece of separate geometry